# Printing a webpage selection with properly formatted math characters

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, ventura

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to print a selection of a webpage with math symbols.

If I select a portion of the webpage to print the math symbols are corrupted.

However if I print the entire webpage the math symbols are correctly formatted.

Steps to reproduce in Chrome (116.0.5845.140 (Official Build) (arm64)) on MacOS (13.5 (22G74))

1. Select text and print selection using right click menu[image]
2. Save PDF using

Example of PDF from selection

Comment: Your best bet is to make a PDF of a complete page, and then crop it in Preview or other PDF editor after.